# If/else if always goes to else statement

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm trying to make a function that determines commission based on user entered amount. It takes a user entered double and uses it to determine which equation it is used in. But the code I wrote always goes to the else statement, and I am not sure what is wrong with my conditions.

```
double calculate(double s)
{
    double c;
    if (s > 300,000)
    {
        c = 25,000 + (0.15 * (s-300,000));
        cout << "went to if" << endl;
        return c;

    }

    else if (300,000 > s && s > 100,000)
    {
        c = 5,000 + (0.10 * (s-100,000));
        cout << "went to else if" << endl;
        return c;

    }

    else
    {
        c = 0.05 * s;
        cout << "went to else" << endl;
        return c;

    }
}
```

Comment: @krzaq How?? Seriously?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ both are about misuse of operator `,`.

Comment: @krzaq Maybe, but not clearly enough for a dupe. C'mon.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ this feels like a minefield. I answer a too trivial question - I get yelled at. I vote to close as a dupe instead - same ;)

Comment: @krzaq _" feels like a minefield"_ It is one of course :)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm glad I'm not a sapper.

Comment: @krzaq This question is just so naive and cute, it deserved an answer :P

Comment: Ugh...it is so obvious in retrospect...

Comment: @gingikid We're mostly answering the obvious stuff. Otherwise the questions get closed as _unclear_, _missing MCVE_, aso. ;)

Comment: I thought it was a problem with the logical/relational operators. Now that I think about it, I guess I could have substituted small values like 1 and 2 to see if the problem was with the values in the conditions. Then I think I would have found the comma mistake...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`s > 300,000` is a **comma expression**, equivalent to `(s > 300),000`. The value of a comma expression is the value of the last one in the list, here `000`. Which evaluates as `false` when converted to `bool`.

You can write that as

```
if( s > 300'000 )
```

or, if the compiler doesn't support that newfangled notation, as just

```
if( s > 300000 )
```

Or you can define

```
double const k = 1000;
```

and write

```
if( s > 300*k )
```

And similarly for the 25 000, 100 000 and 5000 literals.

Comment: That worked, thank you! I should have checked that when I was testing it. I ran the program the first time, entering the amount with a comma in it, and got an incorrect amount. I should have realized it then!

Comment: Also, you could declare the string literal "k" as a user-defined literal to multiply the given integer by 1000.

Comment: @StackDanny: Yes, thanks, good idea, but I think the above is the easiest to understand when looking at the source code (as opposed to writing it). Maybe. Not sure.

Answer (score 18):

What was intended as a number `300,000` in

```
if (s > 300,000)
```

is, in fact, a curious use of [`,`-operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), which is parsed as

```
if ((s > 300),(000))
```

and results in `false` all the time. Instead, try

```
if (s > 300000)
```

(Ditto for `else if (300,000 > s && s > 100,000)` and in a couple of other places.)

Answer (score 4):

`300,000` isn't a proper `double` literal, but applies the comma operator and ends up with the value `0`.

Use a `.` for double literals: `300.000` or no separator for thousands: `300000`

Comment: It could be that a thousand-separator was meant, not `.`.

Comment: @AlexD I mentioned that?

Comment: @AlexD Better, yes ;)